# Error installing angular generator

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm attempting to use Node to install an angular package for yeoman. Here's the command I run

"npm install -g generator-angular"

Everything seems to work until I get this error

```
node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: "pre" versions of node cannot be installed, use the --nodedir flag instead
gyp ERR! stack     at install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:65:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.self.commands.(anonymous function) [as install] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js:66:37)
gyp ERR! stack     at getNodeDir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:150:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:93:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:659:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:101:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:773:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:840:5)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-37-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/angular/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.11.10-pre
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Further down, it returns this error.

```
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/angular/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/cssstyle/lib/properties/webkitFlexFlow.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-37-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "generator" "angular"
npm ERR! cwd /home/colin
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.10-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.15
npm ERR! path /home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/angular/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/cssstyle/lib/properties/webkitFlexFlow.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/angular/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/cssstyle/lib/properties/webkitFlexFlow.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:97:15)
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/angular/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/test'
npm ERR! error rolling back  jsdom@0.8.11 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/angular/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/test']
npm ERR! error rolling back   stack: 'Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir \'/home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/angular/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/test\'',
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -39,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/angular/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/test' }
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/angular/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/ctype/tst/ctf/tst.fail.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-37-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "generator" "angular"
npm ERR! cwd /home/colin
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.10-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.15
npm ERR! path /home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/angular/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/ctype/tst/ctf/tst.fail.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing hawk@1.0.0
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/angular/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules'
npm ERR! error rolling back  angular@1.2.16 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/angular/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules']
npm ERR! error rolling back   stack: 'Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir \'/home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/angular/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules\'',
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -39,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/angular/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/node_modules' }
npm ERR! contextify@0.1.8 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.8 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls contextify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-37-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "generator" "angular"
npm ERR! cwd /home/colin
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.10-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.15
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/punycode
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/colin/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I tried "npm install contextify", and I was met with this:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angularnpm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/install
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generator
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/generator
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angularnpm
npm ERR! 404 'angularnpm' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-37-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "generator" "angularnpm" "install" "contextify"
npm ERR! cwd /home/colin
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.10-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.15
npm ERR! code E404
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/install
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/colin/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I changed the permissions of my local directory with

"sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/"

I'm thinking this is a permissions or PATH error, but I have no idea what I'm dealing with here.

Could this be because of a Yeoman issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's not

```
npm install -g generator angular
```

it's

```
npm install -g generator-angular
```

with the dash between generator and angular.

Comment: You're right, I accidentally wrote that incorrectly in this post. I'll fix it.